# MS Excel VBA code to create hide / delete rules

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I'm looking for help with a simple task on Excel using VBA.

What I'm trying to accomplish and would greatly help me in my work is to create simple rule that would do something like below:

```
For Each c In Range("Row(2))
If c.Value = 0 Then
    c.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
ElseIf c.Value = >0 Then
    c.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
End If
```

My goal is simply to be able to make zero value on row 2 make the entire column hidden when row 2 of that column equals zero.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you are not using a filter? Press Data->Filter and see how the first row suddenly has little down arrows at the right. Press the down arrow on the corresponding column where you want rows to be hidden, and select when not 0. It will show all rows that are not 0.

Comment: he wants to hide the column, not rows

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answers, filter would work greatly for rows but the issue is hiding colums, which is afaik not possible with filter. The amount of data is fairly large so "hiding automatically" would be most optimal solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try something like the below:

```
Sub hide()
Application.Calculation = xlManual
ActiveSheet.Cells.EntireColumn.Hidden = False

'600 represents 600 columns, adjust to suit your range
For i = 1 To 600

If InStr(Cells(2, i).Value, "0") And Columns(i).Hidden = False Then
    Columns(i).Hidden = True

End If

Next i

Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic

End Sub
```

Comment: This will hide rows, not columns.

Comment: updated it, should work just fine now

Comment: Hello @User91504 thank you for the solution, works perfectly.